# I'm executing a query which returns count . Throws exception when i try to get value from resultSet

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Query :

```
 select count(*) from table_name
```

DB: Sqlserver

```
totalrowcount = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(1));
```

When I try to execute a query which returns the count, an exception is thrown while I try to get the value from `resultSet`.

Exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'count'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.heb.endeca.util.BatchManagerHelper.getRowCount(BatchManagerHelper.java:91)
    at com.heb.endeca.util.BatchManagerHelper.generateFeed(BatchManagerHelper.java:70)
    at com.heb.endeca.batch.BatchManager.startEndecaBatchManager(BatchManager.java:87)
    at com.heb.endeca.batch.BatchManager.main(BatchManager.java:50)
```

Comment: Can we see more of your code ? How do you execute that query precisely ? My initial thought, however, is that getString() is not what you'd use to retrieve a count

Comment: statement = connection.createStatement(); LOG.debug("Statement created for pricecountquery"); resultSet = statement.executeQuery(countQuery); if(resultSet.next()) System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1)); This is my code. Still it throws com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'count' -- Exception like this though resultset.next() returns true

Comment: don't add your code as a comment, edit the original post. people are going to read the post, not necessarily the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Count returns a numeric value.

```
select count(*) num_rows from table_name

totalrowcount = 0;

if(rs.next())
{
    totalrowcount = rs.getInt("num_rows");
}
```